# Using a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT how do I specify a WITH condition (CTE)?

Tags: postgresql, cte, syntax, sql-standard, ctas

There is an old and deprecated command in PostgreSQL that predates [`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` (CTAS) called `SELECT ... INTO .... FROM`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156105/2639), it supports `WITH` clauses / Common Table Expressions (CTE). So, for instance, I can do this..

```
WITH w AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
)
SELECT *
INTO foo
FROM w;
```

But, I can't do this..

```
WITH w AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
)
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT * FROM w;
```

Or, I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 5: CREATE TABLE foo AS
```

How would I do that using the standardized CTAS syntax.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It may be awkward, but you have to move the `WITH` clause from the top into the query. It's a part of the statement to generate the table, and that statement comes *after* the `CREATE TABLE`, so you would use this syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
WITH w AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
)
SELECT * FROM w;
```

Also worth noting that it's *not* explicit in the [official docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) it just falls under *query*

```
CREATE [ [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } | UNLOGGED ] TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] table_name
    [ (column_name [, ...] ) ]
    [ WITH ( storage_parameter [= value] [, ... ] ) | WITH OIDS | WITHOUT OIDS ]
    [ ON COMMIT { PRESERVE ROWS | DELETE ROWS | DROP } ]
    [ TABLESPACE tablespace_name ]
    AS query
    [ WITH [ NO ] DATA ]
```

The docs mention two *other* use cases for the `WITH` keyword,

1. To set [`storage_options`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS)
2. To set `NO DATA`

You can see both of them in use like this,

```
CREATE TABLE foo
WITH (fillfactor = 100)
AS
  WITH w AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
  )
  SELECT * FROM w
WITH NO DATA;
```

Now you've got a table with nothing.

```
TABLE foo;
 x 
---
(0 rows)
```

Comment: If only it were consistent... the `INSERT` statement requires the CTE for the _query_ part before the `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the CREATE TABLE AS needed to go before the WITH. That's an unfortunate inconsistency.