# Postgresql: when temporary tables are deleted in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, temporary-tables

I am inserting data into temp table and its working fine. below is the psedo sql code for the same

```
with cte as(

)
select * 
into temp_table
from cte
```

with this approach data is inserted very fast into temp table. As per my knowleged temp table is deleted once the session is closed. but my temp table is not deleted even if closed my pgadmin connection.

My question is does temp table in postgresql are deleted automatically or they remains on disk space until we delete them.

Regards,

Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: Unrelated, but: the non-standard `select into ... from ...` is discouraged. Use `create table ... as select ...` to create a table from the result of a select statement.

Comment: will i tried this but somehow this approach is taking more time to insert query into table. don't know why??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact you created a regular table. You have to specify that this is a temporary table:

```
with cte as(
-- <a_query>
)
select * 
into temporary temp_table
from cte;
```

or (the recommended syntax):

```
create temporary table temp_table as
-- <a_query>
```

See [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html) and [CREATE TABLE AS.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

Comment: klin: Does that mean that i am not creating temporary table here

Comment: Yes, you need a word `temporary` like in the answer.

Comment: [CREATE TABLE AS vs SELECT INTO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156105/2639) answer on [dba.se]

Answer (score 7):

According to [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtable.html) temporary tables are dropped at end of a session or at end of a transaction.

> **TEMPORARY or TEMP**
>
> If specified, the table is created as a temporary table. **Temporary
>   tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or
>   optionally at the end of the current transaction** (see ON COMMIT
>   below). Existing permanent tables with the same name are not visible
>   to the current session while the temporary table exists, unless they
>   are referenced with schema-qualified names. Any indexes created on a
>   temporary table are automatically temporary as well.

Comment: do you have any idea when temp_schema are dropped?