# Is there a way to create temporary tables using CTE's and WITH/VALUES in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to create a temporary table using CTE's/With.

Is there a Vertica equivalent for this approach?

```
WITH  vals (k,v) AS (VALUES (0,-9999), (1, 100)) 
SELECT * FROM vals;
```

I want to be able to use the data without creating a temp table

[How to create a temporary table using VALUES in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86724/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-using-values-in-postgresql)

Comment: Have you tried `WITH vals (k, v) AS (SELECT 0, -9999 UNION SELECT 1, 100) SELECT * FROM vals;`? See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6af038f5c3bce45f1be48cc19e6b144d). If this works, I can write it up! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: I have but it seems unelegant with all the unions.

Comment: Yes, but does it work? :-)

Comment: Haha. Yes, it works. Just looking for alternatives.

Comment: I don't think even Oracle has the `VALUES` clause in this context! Ah well, so much for my answer...

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks for your input.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you go to orafaq.com and look through the SQL forum there, it's stuffed to the gills with `SELECT BLAH FROM DUAL UNION....`